# CORS blocks redirect to Spring OAuth login on localhost page due to "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Header'"

Tags: spring-boot, spring-security-oauth2

I've got two apps running on different localhost ports, and the first calls a Spring Boot application that requires authorization.

The Spring Boot application tries to redirect from  `localhost:samenumber/url to localhost:samenumber/login`.

I know that I can use

```
@CrossOrigin(origins = "localhost:otherport")
```

as an annotation for a method to allow `localhost:otherport` to access a method, but I don't actually have a method in a controller that handles `/login`.

I simply annotated my application's main class with `@EnableOAuth2Sso`, and am not sure what else to change to allow redirects to `localhost:samenumber/login`